# Agora Flexible classroom - Chat not working

Tags: agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I just launched agora flexible classroom. But the chat module is not working and it's showing this console error. How do I solve this issue and chat work?
Here are my codes. Please check:
SDK:

```
AgoraEduSDK.config({
                // Here pass in the Agora App ID you have got
                appId: self.agora_id,
            })
            AgoraEduSDK.launch(
                document.querySelector("#classroom"), {
                    // Here pass in the RTM token you have generated
                    rtmToken: self.token,
                    // The user ID must be the same as the one you used for generating the RTM token
                    userUuid: self.authuserid,
                    userName: self.authuser,
                    roomUuid: "6441444714144", //Should be unique and generate when join
                    roomName: "demo-class", //Any
                    roleType: 1, //teacher = 1, student = 2, assistant = 3
                    roomType: 4, // Room1v1Class = 0, RoomBigClass = 2, RoomSmallClass = 4
                    pretest: true,
                    language: "en",
                    startTime: new Date().getTime(),
                    duration: 60 * 30, // dynamic time
                    courseWareList: [],
                    listener: (evt) => {
                        if (evt == 1){
                            this.joined = true //Ready
                        }
                        if (evt == 2){
                            this.joined = false //Leave
                        }
                        console.log("evt", evt)
                    }
                }
            )
```

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaSGX.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest double checking your config especially your RTM token (which is different from the RTC Token). You're using variable for a few properties, try logging those out to make sure the values are correct - the error in your image suggests the passed JSON has some syntax issue. If you're still facing issues you can open a support ticket using the Agora console.